# How to specify output directory for Entity Framework Model-First entity generation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We are using Entity Framework 6 with Model-First, which by default results that our entities, the dbcontext, the .tt files, and the model files are crammed in a single folder, without any structure.

I would like to achieve some separation, at least something like this:

Project root/Entities/entities generated from model
Project root/Repository/everything else (.tt, .edmx, etc...)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not. EF is in charge of where it puts stuff and where it expects them to be; you can't change that.

Comment: I don't know who the heck down-voted this. According to all my research, this is the right answer. I'll wait for a few more hours then accept it and upvote it.

Comment: Thank you, Kornél. Cheers -

Answer (score 1):

What you could do in order to get a bit closer to what you want is to use [EntityFramework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) to reverse engineer the database and produce a set of POCO classes that can be used as your data access.

It's often described as Code-Second I believe.

You can installed the Power Tools and then select the location in your solution where you want the classes to be and then right-click and select "Reverse Engineer Database" {sic}

Comment: The result is a Code-First EF model. It's not good for my situation, but gave an upvote for the nice idea.

Comment: Thanks, just out of interest what does having all the EDMX complication buy you that you really need?  The POCO approach is much nicer to work with.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. I'll do some more research on the topic, and if I find your solution better, then I'll propose to my team members to switch the way we use EF (we are in a big refactoring anyways).

Comment: Ever since the LinqToSql days prior to EF I found the `.dbml` and then the `.edmx` files more of a pain than a pleasure to be honest.  Massively overweight and not very conducive to editing outside a designer.  Whereas having a set of essentially more or less plain POCO classes just makes the whole process so much "thinner" and far more familiar to developers.  Combine it with migrations and script output of migrations (rather than auto run from the Package Manager Console) and you have a powerful and simple approach.

Answer (score 0):

sure you can! I don't know what do you mean by

```
Project root/Entities/entities generated from model
Project root/Repository/everything else (.tt, .edmx, etc...)
```

but you can even separate the assembly. you can have you domain entities, repository and Context class in an assembly or in a namespace.(it's better to do that for make you app maintainable). take a look at [this](http://ehsanghanbari.com/Post/6/getting-started-with-entity-framework) and [this](http://ehsanghanbari.com/Post/8/repository-pattern-practice-in-data-access-layer-via-entity-framework) blog posts. hope it helps

Comment: I asked Model-First. What you linked is Code-First. Please remove your answer before people start downvoting it. (also un-downvote 'simon at rcl's answer if it was you who downvoted it)

Comment: I think it's better to edit your question to data first, code first is an idiom in entity framework work actually you create model when you are working with code first! sorry I thought you mean by model first is the same

Comment: "Model First" is an official Microsoft expression, existing since EF 4.0, when 'code first' didn't even exist. My question even mentions .edmx files, which clearly shows that it's not code first.

Comment: you are right, I didn't noticed about that but mention the "Data Fist" in your question.

Comment: Data(base) First and Model First are not the same either. Database First - You first have the database and generate the model based on that. Model First - You first make a model then generate the database and the code based on that.

Comment: I can't see how either link pertains to the question at all. Sorry.